# Bs4 fail when try to get next url

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

There is my code

```
def parser():
    flag = True
    url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com'
    while flag:
        responce = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, 'html.parser')
        quote_l = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'text'})
        q_count = 0
        for i in range(len(quote_l)):
            if q_count >= 5:
                flag = False
                break
            quote = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'text'})[i]
            if not Quote.objects.filter(quote=quote.string).exists():
                author = soup.find_all('small', {'class': 'author'})[i]
                if not Author.objects.filter(name=author.string).exists():
                    a = Author.objects.create(name=author.string)
                    Quote.objects.create(quote=quote.string, author_id=a.id)
                    q_count += 1
                else:
                    a = Author.objects.get(name=author.string)
                    Quote.objects.create(quote=quote.string, author_id=a.id)
                    q_count += 1


        url += soup.find('li', {'class': 'next'}).a['href']
```

I need to get the next page but I have this Exc. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'

How to fix that and maybe how I can optimize my Code.Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reaching the last page there will be no Next button so you need an exit condition check prior to attempting to access the href for next page. One possibility would be to add the following lines before your current last line:

```
next_page = soup.find('li', {'class': 'next'})
if not next_page: flag = False  # or return
```

Or simply `return` at that point.

You'd also update the last line to use the variable, of course, and ensure you are not continuously extending url with suffixes of next page. For example, one could add the suffix during the requests call:

```
def parser():
    flag = True
    url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com'
    suffix = ''

    while flag:
        responce = requests.get(url + suffix)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, 'html.parser')
        # other code
        
        
        next_page = soup.find('li', {'class': 'next'})

        if not next_page: 
            return
        suffix = next_page.a['href']
```

Comment: Changed.Have the same Exc.'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: You are creating the wrong next page url by using += since URL is before the loop but altered within.

Comment: It's works.Thank you. I need only 5 quotes when my script works, but I have 10.Can u help me with it

Comment: I am not clear if you need to visit more than one page and get 5 quotes from each? Or one page and get 5 quotes. I also don't know what `Quote.objects` is or the Author one. Are these custom classes? It's helpful to ensure that your code is runnable as shown and gives the expected error messages. If there are lines of code that aren't needed then remove then whilst preserving the overall logic. The error should be reproducible whatever decisions you make.

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question, include the minimal code to reproduce your current issue, explaining what should happen, what is happening, and what you have tried in order to solve. Include the import statements and any other class references if necessary to the [mcve].

Comment: I need 5 quotes from one page

Comment: ok, understand, thank you

Comment: @QHarr Taking a look [as my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74965478/12349734) do you think that the `cookies` are loaded _dynamically_? which means, that the OP will need to keep on changing them, or are the `cookies` fixed, so they can just use my example?

Comment: I think you possibly only need a matching cookie and `data` param pair. So, `cookies = {"wf_csrf_c": ""}`  and then a match in the params of  `"wf_csrf": ""`.  One blank cookie and a blank param  value. @MendelG You can likely simplify/remove a lot of the other params within `data` as well.