# Selenium Python: How do I get the "data-original-title" information from a website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get some information from https://wefut.com/player-database/22. In particular, the nation of the players. I've been using Selenium to get the rest of the information and it worked fine. However, I couldn't find a way to access the country, an example:

`<a href="/nation/54/23" title="" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Brazil">`

I tried something like `(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_country)).get_attribute('data-original-title')`

But that just returns None. I couldn't find any useful information about this. Is there a way to do this, using Selenium or any other library? If not, I'm open to suggestions on other ways to obtain the information (maybe easily).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no need to use `Selenium` for this case. If you inspect your browsers Network calls (Click on F12) you'll see that the data is loaded *dynamicallly* via sending a `POST` request to:

```
https://wefut.com/ajax/getPlayers/22
```

So, to get the data, you can use this example, you can acess the data with their `keys`/`values` as a normal `dict`.

*Note, I'm not sure if the `cookies` you need to get the dynamically or not*. If so, you can use a tools such as [curlconverter.com](https://curlconverter.com/)

```py
import requests


cookies = {
    "wf_csrf_c": "98ca71d90e465992b20ed99bb6f48863",
    "wf_sc": "ZENmE3GNNzYhW5MFyUUs2DUgdnTWjaSTeT5gxrukYIXWclPvLdUtqZ7RmKU8UWje%2Fyz4hvcoEnXQw5HlhuYH%2FL6a3RzD%2BnWf4%2B9oCza3eVgTR7fRIzD6oY%2BVb27h1Yti7p1pwh4lOk%2F%2BrOrLD3ZXvoEoCw9APyV23hKcYE8EAXeCPYjPCwwnN8S8ZSuJVmcRsTbfir%2FPTu9okyWD11iEyWkd5nNU5rV65Qlcn%2FqKVKFECEnvLa%2FdzkgkfGOmLwNCtasEoba6hVROw8PNwzNvUilBbLNrVmkfbk3f4ZmxpXkDS1eEfrbyp%2BsriZMKk%2BlrOd2%2F%2FCRqY8W%2F1Vuv0ibMZ2fnsdBq39pUMVhqCjZO8AFHVt9u7tT9EBCSj7Ded%2Ffcdq4gugjpPQZY1wTa4Tw3YdDl%2BiBHHkoDA6FWY3ZA82QIPnnnAl8WZAH8y%2Fb%2BeV%2BWx5Cojm4w30DebGAo7xnwBg%3D%3D",
    "_ga": "GA1.2.577503996.1672430468",
    "_gid": "GA1.2.1097143011.1672430468",
    "_gat_gtag_UA_39374027_1": "1",
}


data = {
    "sEcho": "1",
    "iColumns": "75",
    "sColumns": "",
    "iDisplayStart": "0",
    "iDisplayLength": "25",
    "mDataProp_0": "0",
    "mDataProp_1": "1",
    "mDataProp_2": "2",
    "mDataProp_3": "3",
    "mDataProp_4": "4",
    "mDataProp_5": "5",
    "mDataProp_6": "6",
    "mDataProp_7": "7",
    "mDataProp_8": "8",
    "mDataProp_9": "9",
    "mDataProp_10": "10",
    "mDataProp_11": "11",
    "mDataProp_12": "12",
    "mDataProp_13": "13",
    "mDataProp_14": "14",
    "mDataProp_15": "15",
    "mDataProp_16": "16",
    "mDataProp_17": "17",
    "mDataProp_18": "18",
    "mDataProp_19": "19",
    "mDataProp_20": "20",
    "mDataProp_21": "21",
    "mDataProp_22": "22",
    "mDataProp_23": "23",
    "mDataProp_24": "24",
    "mDataProp_25": "25",
    "mDataProp_26": "26",
    "mDataProp_27": "27",
    "mDataProp_28": "28",
    "mDataProp_29": "29",
    "mDataProp_30": "30",
    "mDataProp_31": "31",
    "mDataProp_32": "32",
    "mDataProp_33": "33",
    "mDataProp_34": "34",
    "mDataProp_35": "35",
    "mDataProp_36": "36",
    "mDataProp_37": "37",
    "mDataProp_38": "38",
    "mDataProp_39": "39",
    "mDataProp_40": "40",
    "mDataProp_41": "41",
    "mDataProp_42": "42",
    "mDataProp_43": "43",
    "mDataProp_44": "44",
    "mDataProp_45": "45",
    "mDataProp_46": "46",
    "mDataProp_47": "47",
    "mDataProp_48": "48",
    "mDataProp_49": "49",
    "mDataProp_50": "50",
    "mDataProp_51": "51",
    "mDataProp_52": "52",
    "mDataProp_53": "53",
    "mDataProp_54": "54",
    "mDataProp_55": "55",
    "mDataProp_56": "56",
    "mDataProp_57": "57",
    "mDataProp_58": "58",
    "mDataProp_59": "59",
    "mDataProp_60": "60",
    "mDataProp_61": "61",
    "mDataProp_62": "62",
    "mDataProp_63": "63",
    "mDataProp_64": "64",
    "mDataProp_65": "65",
    "mDataProp_66": "66",
    "mDataProp_67": "67",
    "mDataProp_68": "68",
    "mDataProp_69": "69",
    "mDataProp_70": "70",
    "mDataProp_71": "71",
    "mDataProp_72": "72",
    "mDataProp_73": "73",
    "mDataProp_74": "74",
    "sSearch": "",
    "bRegex": "false",
    "sSearch_0": "",
    "bRegex_0": "false",
    "bSearchable_0": "true",
    "sSearch_1": "",
    "bRegex_1": "false",
    "bSearchable_1": "true",
    "sSearch_2": "",
    "bRegex_2": "false",
    "bSearchable_2": "true",
    "sSearch_3": "",
    "bRegex_3": "false",
    "bSearchable_3": "true",
    "sSearch_4": "",
    "bRegex_4": "false",
    "bSearchable_4": "true",
    "sSearch_5": "",
    "bRegex_5": "false",
    "bSearchable_5": "true",
    "sSearch_6": "",
    "bRegex_6": "false",
    "bSearchable_6": "true",
    "sSearch_7": "",
    "bRegex_7": "false",
    "bSearchable_7": "true",
    "sSearch_8": "",
    "bRegex_8": "false",
    "bSearchable_8": "true",
    "sSearch_9": "",
    "bRegex_9": "false",
    "bSearchable_9": "true",
    "sSearch_10": "",
    "bRegex_10": "false",
    "bSearchable_10": "true",
    "sSearch_11": "",
    "bRegex_11": "false",
    "bSearchable_11": "true",
    "sSearch_12": "",
    "bRegex_12": "false",
    "bSearchable_12": "true",
    "sSearch_13": "",
    "bRegex_13": "false",
    "bSearchable_13": "true",
    "sSearch_14": "",
    "bRegex_14": "false",
    "bSearchable_14": "true",
    "sSearch_15": "",
    "bRegex_15": "false",
    "bSearchable_15": "true",
    "sSearch_16": "",
    "bRegex_16": "false",
    "bSearchable_16": "true",
    "sSearch_17": "",
    "bRegex_17": "false",
    "bSearchable_17": "true",
    "sSearch_18": "",
    "bRegex_18": "false",
    "bSearchable_18": "true",
    "sSearch_19": "",
    "bRegex_19": "false",
    "bSearchable_19": "true",
    "sSearch_20": "",
    "bRegex_20": "false",
    "bSearchable_20": "true",
    "sSearch_21": "",
    "bRegex_21": "false",
    "bSearchable_21": "true",
    "sSearch_22": "",
    "bRegex_22": "false",
    "bSearchable_22": "true",
    "sSearch_23": "",
    "bRegex_23": "false",
    "bSearchable_23": "true",
    "sSearch_24": "",
    "bRegex_24": "false",
    "bSearchable_24": "true",
    "sSearch_25": "",
    "bRegex_25": "false",
    "bSearchable_25": "true",
    "sSearch_26": "",
    "bRegex_26": "false",
    "bSearchable_26": "true",
    "sSearch_27": "",
    "bRegex_27": "false",
    "bSearchable_27": "true",
    "sSearch_28": "",
    "bRegex_28": "false",
    "bSearchable_28": "true",
    "sSearch_29": "",
    "bRegex_29": "false",
    "bSearchable_29": "true",
    "sSearch_30": "",
    "bRegex_30": "false",
    "bSearchable_30": "true",
    "sSearch_31": "",
    "bRegex_31": "false",
    "bSearchable_31": "true",
    "sSearch_32": "",
    "bRegex_32": "false",
    "bSearchable_32": "true",
    "sSearch_33": "",
    "bRegex_33": "false",
    "bSearchable_33": "true",
    "sSearch_34": "",
    "bRegex_34": "false",
    "bSearchable_34": "true",
    "sSearch_35": "",
    "bRegex_35": "false",
    "bSearchable_35": "true",
    "sSearch_36": "",
    "bRegex_36": "false",
    "bSearchable_36": "true",
    "sSearch_37": "",
    "bRegex_37": "false",
    "bSearchable_37": "true",
    "sSearch_38": "",
    "bRegex_38": "false",
    "bSearchable_38": "true",
    "sSearch_39": "",
    "bRegex_39": "false",
    "bSearchable_39": "true",
    "sSearch_40": "",
    "bRegex_40": "false",
    "bSearchable_40": "true",
    "sSearch_41": "",
    "bRegex_41": "false",
    "bSearchable_41": "true",
    "sSearch_42": "",
    "bRegex_42": "false",
    "bSearchable_42": "true",
    "sSearch_43": "",
    "bRegex_43": "false",
    "bSearchable_43": "true",
    "sSearch_44": "",
    "bRegex_44": "false",
    "bSearchable_44": "true",
    "sSearch_45": "",
    "bRegex_45": "false",
    "bSearchable_45": "true",
    "sSearch_46": "",
    "bRegex_46": "false",
    "bSearchable_46": "true",
    "sSearch_47": "",
    "bRegex_47": "false",
    "bSearchable_47": "true",
    "sSearch_48": "",
    "bRegex_48": "false",
    "bSearchable_48": "true",
    "sSearch_49": "",
    "bRegex_49": "false",
    "bSearchable_49": "true",
    "sSearch_50": "",
    "bRegex_50": "false",
    "bSearchable_50": "true",
    "sSearch_51": "",
    "bRegex_51": "false",
    "bSearchable_51": "true",
    "sSearch_52": "",
    "bRegex_52": "false",
    "bSearchable_52": "true",
    "sSearch_53": "",
    "bRegex_53": "false",
    "bSearchable_53": "true",
    "sSearch_54": "",
    "bRegex_54": "false",
    "bSearchable_54": "true",
    "sSearch_55": "",
    "bRegex_55": "false",
    "bSearchable_55": "true",
    "sSearch_56": "",
    "bRegex_56": "false",
    "bSearchable_56": "true",
    "sSearch_57": "",
    "bRegex_57": "false",
    "bSearchable_57": "true",
    "sSearch_58": "",
    "bRegex_58": "false",
    "bSearchable_58": "true",
    "sSearch_59": "",
    "bRegex_59": "false",
    "bSearchable_59": "true",
    "sSearch_60": "",
    "bRegex_60": "false",
    "bSearchable_60": "true",
    "sSearch_61": "",
    "bRegex_61": "false",
    "bSearchable_61": "true",
    "sSearch_62": "",
    "bRegex_62": "false",
    "bSearchable_62": "true",
    "sSearch_63": "",
    "bRegex_63": "false",
    "bSearchable_63": "true",
    "sSearch_64": "",
    "bRegex_64": "false",
    "bSearchable_64": "true",
    "sSearch_65": "",
    "bRegex_65": "false",
    "bSearchable_65": "true",
    "sSearch_66": "",
    "bRegex_66": "false",
    "bSearchable_66": "true",
    "sSearch_67": "",
    "bRegex_67": "false",
    "bSearchable_67": "true",
    "sSearch_68": "",
    "bRegex_68": "false",
    "bSearchable_68": "true",
    "sSearch_69": "",
    "bRegex_69": "false",
    "bSearchable_69": "true",
    "sSearch_70": "",
    "bRegex_70": "false",
    "bSearchable_70": "true",
    "sSearch_71": "",
    "bRegex_71": "false",
    "bSearchable_71": "true",
    "sSearch_72": "",
    "bRegex_72": "false",
    "bSearchable_72": "true",
    "sSearch_73": "",
    "bRegex_73": "false",
    "bSearchable_73": "true",
    "sSearch_74": "",
    "bRegex_74": "false",
    "bSearchable_74": "true",
    "iSortCol_0": "4",
    "sSortDir_0": "desc",
    "iSortingCols": "1",
    "bSortable_0": "false",
    "bSortable_1": "true",
    "bSortable_2": "true",
    "bSortable_3": "true",
    "bSortable_4": "true",
    "bSortable_5": "true",
    "bSortable_6": "true",
    "bSortable_7": "true",
    "bSortable_8": "false",
    "bSortable_9": "true",
    "bSortable_10": "true",
    "bSortable_11": "true",
    "bSortable_12": "true",
    "bSortable_13": "true",
    "bSortable_14": "true",
    "bSortable_15": "true",
    "bSortable_16": "true",
    "bSortable_17": "true",
    "bSortable_18": "true",
    "bSortable_19": "true",
    "bSortable_20": "true",
    "bSortable_21": "true",
    "bSortable_22": "true",
    "bSortable_23": "true",
    "bSortable_24": "true",
    "bSortable_25": "true",
    "bSortable_26": "true",
    "bSortable_27": "true",
    "bSortable_28": "true",
    "bSortable_29": "true",
    "bSortable_30": "true",
    "bSortable_31": "true",
    "bSortable_32": "true",
    "bSortable_33": "true",
    "bSortable_34": "true",
    "bSortable_35": "true",
    "bSortable_36": "true",
    "bSortable_37": "true",
    "bSortable_38": "true",
    "bSortable_39": "true",
    "bSortable_40": "true",
    "bSortable_41": "true",
    "bSortable_42": "true",
    "bSortable_43": "true",
    "bSortable_44": "true",
    "bSortable_45": "true",
    "bSortable_46": "true",
    "bSortable_47": "true",
    "bSortable_48": "true",
    "bSortable_49": "true",
    "bSortable_50": "true",
    "bSortable_51": "true",
    "bSortable_52": "true",
    "bSortable_53": "true",
    "bSortable_54": "true",
    "bSortable_55": "true",
    "bSortable_56": "true",
    "bSortable_57": "true",
    "bSortable_58": "true",
    "bSortable_59": "true",
    "bSortable_60": "true",
    "bSortable_61": "true",
    "bSortable_62": "true",
    "bSortable_63": "true",
    "bSortable_64": "true",
    "bSortable_65": "true",
    "bSortable_66": "true",
    "bSortable_67": "true",
    "bSortable_68": "true",
    "bSortable_69": "true",
    "bSortable_70": "true",
    "bSortable_71": "true",
    "bSortable_72": "true",
    "bSortable_73": "false",
    "bSortable_74": "true",
    "min_rating": "40",
    "max_rating": "99",
    "min_pace_tot": "",
    "max_pace_tot": "",
    "min_shooting_tot": "",
    "max_shooting_tot": "",
    "min_passing_tot": "",
    "max_passing_tot": "",
    "min_dribbling_tot": "",
    "max_dribbling_tot": "",
    "min_defending_tot": "",
    "max_defending_tot": "",
    "min_heading_tot": "",
    "max_heading_tot": "",
    "min_acceleration": "",
    "max_acceleration": "",
    "min_agility": "",
    "max_agility": "",
    "min_balance": "",
    "max_balance": "",
    "min_jumping": "",
    "max_jumping": "",
    "min_reactions": "",
    "max_reactions": "",
    "min_sprintspeed": "",
    "max_sprintspeed": "",
    "min_stamina": "",
    "max_stamina": "",
    "min_strength": "",
    "max_strength": "",
    "min_aggression": "",
    "max_aggression": "",
    "min_tact_aware": "",
    "max_tact_aware": "",
    "min_positioning": "",
    "max_positioning": "",
    "min_vision": "",
    "max_vision": "",
    "min_composure": "",
    "max_composure": "",
    "min_potential": "",
    "max_potential": "",
    "min_ball_control": "",
    "max_ball_control": "",
    "min_crossing": "",
    "max_crossing": "",
    "min_curve": "",
    "max_curve": "",
    "min_dribbling": "",
    "max_dribbling": "",
    "min_finishing": "",
    "max_finishing": "",
    "min_fk_acc": "",
    "max_fk_acc": "",
    "min_heading_acc": "",
    "max_heading_acc": "",
    "min_longpass": "",
    "max_longpass": "",
    "min_longshot": "",
    "max_longshot": "",
    "min_marking": "",
    "max_marking": "",
    "min_penalties": "",
    "max_penalties": "",
    "min_shortpass": "",
    "max_shortpass": "",
    "min_shotpower": "",
    "max_shotpower": "",
    "min_sliding_tackle": "",
    "max_sliding_tackle": "",
    "min_standing_tackle": "",
    "max_standing_tackle": "",
    "min_volleys": "",
    "max_volleys": "",
    "min_gk_diving": "",
    "max_gk_diving": "",
    "min_gk_handling": "",
    "max_gk_handling": "",
    "min_gk_kicking": "",
    "max_gk_kicking": "",
    "min_gk_reflexes": "",
    "max_gk_reflexes": "",
    "min_gk_speed": "",
    "max_gk_speed": "",
    "min_gk_positioning": "",
    "max_gk_positioning": "",
    "min_height": "",
    "max_height": "",
    "min_weight": "",
    "max_weight": "",
    "awr": "[]",
    "dwr": "[]",
    "skillmoves": "[]",
    "weakfoot": "[]",
    "preferredfoot": "[]",
    "console": "2",
    "type": "player",
    "clubs": "[]",
    "nations": "[]",
    "positions": "[]",
    "traits": "[]",
    "minprice": "0",
    "maxprice": "0",
    "cardtype": "[]",
    "min_dob": "",
    "max_dob": "",
    "totw": "",
    "wf_csrf": "98ca71d90e465992b20ed99bb6f48863",
}

response = requests.post(
    "https://wefut.com/ajax/getPlayers/22", cookies=cookies, data=data
).json()

for data in response["aaData"]:
    print(data)
```

Prints (truncated):

```
{'0': '', '1': 'Mohamed', '2': 'Salah', '3': '', '4': '99', '5': '1992-06-15', '6': '175', '7': '0', '8': 'CAM', '9': 'Left', '10': 'Liverpool', '11': 'Premier League', '12': 'Egypt', '13': '99', '14': '99', '15': '96', '16': '99', '17': '54', '18': '88', '19': '98', '20': '99', '21': '99', '22': '82', '23': '99', '24': '99', '25': '99', '26': '88', '27': '77', '28': '66', '29': '99', '30': '98', '31': '0', '32': '98', '33': '96', '34': '99', '35': '99', '36': '99', '37': '85', '38': '70', '39': '92', '40': '98', '41': '46', '42': '99', '43': '98', '44': '98', '45': '48', '46': '52', '47': '99', '48': '0', '49': '0', '50': '0', '51': '0', '52': '0', '53': '0', '54': '5', '55': '5', '56': '<label class="label label-success">H</label>', '57': '<label class="label label-warning">M</label>', '58': '23557/22', '59': '174', '60': '0', '61': None, '62': '0', '63': '9', '64': '13', '65': '111', '66': '209331', '67': '99', '68': 0, '69': 0, '70': 'Salah', '71': 'gold174', '72': 'pink', '73': 'pink', '74': '<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-success addBuilder" onclick="dbtosquad(23557, \'\', \'Salah\', 174, 22, [\'CAM\'])" rel="tooltip" title="Add to builder"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button>', 'player_card': '<div class="card pink fifa22" data-base-id="209331" data-club-id="9" data-nation-id="111" data-league-id="13" data-rareflag="174">\r\n    <div class="scard pink fifa22" style="position: relative; z-index: 2">\r\n            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/gold174.png?205" alt="" class="player-card">\r\n\r\n            <div class="rating-gradient"></div>\r\n\r\n                        <a href="https://wefut.com/club/9">\r\n                            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/clubbadges/9.png?21" alt="" class="clubbadge">\r\n                        </a>\r\n            \r\n            <div class="avatarholder ">\r\n                <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/playeravatars/209331.png?21" onerror="this.src=\'//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut15/playeravatars/unknown.png\'" alt="" class="avatar">\r\n            </div>\r\n\r\n                        <a href="https://wefut.com/nation/111">\r\n                            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/nation_flag/111.jpg" class="nationflag">\r\n                        </a>\r\n            \r\n            <div class="ratingholder"><span class="rating"  style="border: 0px !important" >99</span></div>\r\n            <span class="position">CAM</span>\r\n            <div class=" name">\r\n            <span class="marquee">Salah</span>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class="attributes ">\r\n                        <span class="loyalty">\r\n                            </span>\r\n            \r\n            \r\n            <span class="pace">99</span>\r\n            <span class="shooting">99</span>\r\n            <span class="passing">96</span>\r\n            <span class="dribbling">99</span>\r\n            <span class="defending">54</span>\r\n            <span class="heading">88</span>\r\n        </div>\r\n                <div class="chembadge chem--1"></div>\r\n            </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n', 'player_url': 'player/22/23557/mohamed-salah'}
{'0': '', '1': 'Ousmane', '2': 'Dembélé', '3': '', '4': '99', '5': '1997-05-15', '6': '178', '7': '0', '8': 'RW', '9': 'Left', '10': 'FC Barcelona', '11': 'LaLiga Santander', '12': 'France', '13': '99', '14': '96', '15': '94', '16': '99', '17': '49', '18': '79', '19': '99', '20': '99', '21': '97', '22': '81', '23': '95', '24': '99', '25': '96', '26': '72', '27': '75', '28': '49', '29': '97', '30': '93', '31': '0', '32': '99', '33': '96', '34': '99', '35': '99', '36': '95', '37': '80', '38': '58', '39': '93', '40': '97', '41': '57', '42': '94', '43': '95', '44': '99', '45': '44', '46': '41', '47': '94', '48': '0', '49': '0', '50': '0', '51': '0', '52': '0', '53': '0', '54': '5', '55': '5', '56': '<label class="label label-success">H</label>', '57': '<label class="label label-warning">M</label>', '58': '22456/22', '59': '174', '60': '0', '61': None, '62': '0', '63': '241', '64': '53', '65': '18', '66': '231443', '67': '96', '68': 0, '69': 0, '70': 'Dembélé', '71': 'gold174', '72': 'pink', '73': 'pink', '74': '<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-success addBuilder" onclick="dbtosquad(22456, \'\', \'Dembélé\', 174, 22, [\'RW\'])" rel="tooltip" title="Add to builder"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button>', 'player_card': '<div class="card pink fifa22" data-base-id="231443" data-club-id="241" data-nation-id="18" data-league-id="53" data-rareflag="174">\r\n    <div class="scard pink fifa22" style="position: relative; z-index: 2">\r\n            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/gold174.png?205" alt="" class="player-card">\r\n\r\n            <div class="rating-gradient"></div>\r\n\r\n                        <a href="https://wefut.com/club/241">\r\n                            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/clubbadges/241.png?21" alt="" class="clubbadge">\r\n                        </a>\r\n            \r\n            <div class="avatarholder ">\r\n                <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/playeravatars/231443.png?21" onerror="this.src=\'//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut15/playeravatars/unknown.png\'" alt="" class="avatar">\r\n            </div>\r\n\r\n                        <a href="https://wefut.com/nation/18">\r\n                            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/nation_flag/18.jpg" class="nationflag">\r\n                        </a>\r\n            \r\n            <div class="ratingholder"><span class="rating"  style="border: 0px !important" >99</span></div>\r\n            <span class="position">RW</span>\r\n            <div class=" name">\r\n            <span class="marquee">Dembélé</span>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class="attributes ">\r\n                        <span class="loyalty">\r\n                            </span>\r\n            \r\n            \r\n            <span class="pace">99</span>\r\n            <span class="shooting">96</span>\r\n            <span class="passing">94</span>\r\n            <span class="dribbling">99</span>\r\n            <span class="defending">49</span>\r\n            <span class="heading">79</span>\r\n        </div>\r\n                <div class="chembadge chem--1"></div>\r\n            </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n', 'player_url': 'player/22/22456/ousmane-dembele'}
{'0': '', '1': 'Raphaël', '2': 'Varane', '3': '', '4': '99', '5': '1993-04-25', '6': '191', '7': '0', '8': 'CB', '9': 'Right', '10': 'Manchester United', '11': 'Premier League', '12': 'France', '13': '96', '14': '61', '15': '80', '16': '83', '17': '99', '18': '98', '19': '95', '20': '80', '21': '60', '22': '98', '23': '99', '24': '96', '25': '95', '26': '99', '27': '97', '28': '99', '29': '69', '30': '80', '31': '0', '32': '93', '33': '50', '34': '56', '35': '76', '36': '57', '37': '63', '38': '98', '39': '94', '40': '66', '41': '98', '42': '53', '43': '96', '44': '65', '45': '98', '46': '99', '47': '52', '48': '0', '49': '0', '50': '0', '51': '0', '52': '0', '53': '0', '54': '3', '55': '2', '56': '<label class="label label-warning">M</label>', '57': '<label class="label label-success">H</label>', '58': '22450/22', '59': '174', '60': '0', '61': None, '62': '0', '63': '11', '64': '13', '65': '18', '66': '201535', '67': '97', '68': 0, '69': 0, '70': 'Varane', '71': 'gold174', '72': 'pink', '73': 'pink', '74': '<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-success addBuilder" onclick="dbtosquad(22450, \'\', \'Varane\', 174, 22, [\'CB\'])" rel="tooltip" title="Add to builder"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button>', 'player_card': '<div class="card pink fifa22" data-base-id="201535" data-club-id="11" data-nation-id="18" data-league-id="13" data-rareflag="174">\r\n    <div class="scard pink fifa22" style="position: relative; z-index: 2">\r\n            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/gold174.png?205" alt="" class="player-card">\r\n\r\n            <div class="rating-gradient"></div>\r\n\r\n                        <a href="https://wefut.com/club/11">\r\n                            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/clubbadges/11.png?21" alt="" class="clubbadge">\r\n                        </a>\r\n            \r\n            <div class="avatarholder ">\r\n                <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/playeravatars/201535.png?21" onerror="this.src=\'//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut15/playeravatars/unknown.png\'" alt="" class="avatar">\r\n            </div>\r\n\r\n                        <a href="https://wefut.com/nation/18">\r\n                            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/nation_flag/18.jpg" class="nationflag">\r\n                        </a>\r\n            \r\n            <div class="ratingholder"><span class="rating"  style="border: 0px !important" >99</span></div>\r\n            <span class="position">CB</span>\r\n            <div class=" name">\r\n            <span class="marquee">Varane</span>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class="attributes ">\r\n                        <span class="loyalty">\r\n                            </span>\r\n            \r\n            \r\n            <span class="pace">96</span>\r\n            <span class="shooting">61</span>\r\n            <span class="passing">80</span>\r\n            <span class="dribbling">83</span>\r\n            <span class="defending">99</span>\r\n            <span class="heading">98</span>\r\n        </div>\r\n                <div class="chembadge chem--1"></div>\r\n            </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n', 'player_url': 'player/22/22450/raphael-varane'}
{'0': '', '1': 'C. Ronaldo', '2': 'dos Santos Aveiro', '3': 'Cristiano Ronaldo', '4': '99', '5': '1985-02-05', '6': '187', '7': '0', '8': 'LW', '9': 'Right', '10': 'Manchester United', '11': 'Premier League', '12': 'Portugal', '13': '99', '14': '99', '15': '90', '16': '97', '17': '50', '18': '92', '19': '99', '20': '97', '21': '90', '22': '99', '23': '99', '24': '99', '25': '95', '26': '95', '27': '81', '28': '47', '29': '99', '30': '91', '31': '0', '32': '98', '33': '94', '34': '93', '35': '97', '36': '99', '37': '91', '38': '99', '39': '85', '40': '99', '41': '38', '42': '93', '43': '90', '44': '99', '45': '39', '46': '50', '47': '95', '48': '0', '49': '0', '50': '0', '51': '0', '52': '0', '53': '0', '54': '4', '55': '5', '56': '<label class="label label-success">H</label>', '57': '<label class="label label-danger">L</label>', '58': '22188/22', '59': '97', '60': '0', '61': None, '62': '0', '63': '11', '64': '13', '65': '38', '66': '20801', '67': '99', '68': 0, '69': 0, '70': 'Cristiano Ronaldo', '71': 'gold97', '72': 'shapeshifters', '73': 'shapeshifters', '74': '<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-success addBuilder" onclick="dbtosquad(22188, \'\', \'Cristiano Ronaldo\', 97, 22, [\'LW\'])" rel="tooltip" title="Add to builder"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button>', 'player_card': '<div class="card shapeshifters fifa22" data-base-id="20801" data-club-id="11" data-nation-id="38" data-league-id="13" data-rareflag="97">\r\n    <div class="scard shapeshifters fifa22" style="position: relative; z-index: 2">\r\n            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/gold97.png?205" alt="" class="player-card">\r\n\r\n            <div class="rating-gradient"></div>\r\n\r\n                        <a href="https://wefut.com/club/11">\r\n                            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/clubbadges/11.png?21" alt="" class="clubbadge">\r\n                        </a>\r\n            \r\n            <div class="avatarholder ">\r\n                <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut22/playeravatars/20801.png?21" onerror="this.src=\'//static.wefut.com/assets/images/fut15/playeravatars/unknown.png\'" alt="" class="avatar">\r\n            </div>\r\n\r\n                        <a href="https://wefut.com/nation/38">\r\n                            <img src="//static.wefut.com/assets/images/nation_flag/38.jpg" class="nationflag">\r\n                        </a>\r\n            \r\n            <div class="ratingholder"><span class="rating"  style="border: 0px !important" >99</span></div>\r\n            <span class="position">LW</span>\r\n            <div class=" name">\r\n            <span class="marquee">Cristiano Ronaldo</span>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <div class="attributes ">\r\n                        <span class="loyalty">\r\n                            </span>\r\n            \r\n            \r\n            <span class="pace">99</span>\r\n            <span class="shooting">99</span>\r\n            <span class="passing">90</span>\r\n            <span class="dribbling">97</span>\r\n            <span class="defending">50</span>\r\n            <span class="heading">92</span>\r\n        </div>\r\n                <div class="chembadge chem--1"></div>\r\n            </div>\r\n    </div>\r\n', 'player_url': 'player/22/22188/cristiano-ronaldo'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have a few questions, I'm not very familiar with this methods that you talk about. Would you mind going into detail about where I can get the cookies, and data variables that you show? I don't quite understand what you are doing, if you can recommend some documentation or something I would apreciate. Sorry if it's a newbie question

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.get('https://httpbin.org')
qw = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body > a')
po = qw.get_attribute('aria-label')
```

this works... so there's probably some issue with your code

try adding a delay before finding element, or use [this method](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

edit: after inspecting the site, countries are in 'title' attributes and 'data-original-title' doesnt exist on the page for me